# CSS: Absolute position text inside relative position div

Tags: css, css-position

Maybe easier to the the site in progress - http://www.roadsafetyforchildren.co.uk/

I want to position the yellow text at the bottom of the page over the blue bar (which is an `img`).

I have a div that has `position:relative;`, within that is another div that has `position:absolute;`. I thought by doing that when you assign a `top` position to the absolute div it will take the top of the relative div as it's starting point? Mine takes the top of the screen as it's starting point, hence the massive top position.

Obviously I want the yellow text to move with the the blue bar depending how tall/wide the page is.

As far as I can see using position absolute is the only way to solve this?

Maybe I'm not understanding the whole notion of putting a absolute positioned div inside a relative one!

Comment: I don't see any parent of the yellow text with position relative on your site.  But yes, an element with absolute position is placed relative to its first relative/absolute parent.  Also - you can use `bottom:0px;` instead of `top:943px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#footer` div is absolutely positioned but it is not within any relatively positioned element.  The only relative element I see is `#actual-content`, which is a sibling of `#footer`.  If you place an absolutely positioned element WITHIN a relative element then it acts as you described.

Answer (score 1):

The absolutely positioned div must be *inside* the relatively positioned div.  That doesn't seem to be the case on the site you've linked.